# Find cells that are duplicated more than specific number in a text column in excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have an excel file that have a text column and several numbers columns. The text column has several duplicated values. I want to find the cells that are duplicated more than specific number like duplicated more than 9 times. Does anyone knows how can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: countif/countifs

Comment: @Jeeped Thank you for your comment. I would like to ask you please for more details please to make it clear how can I use it in this situation. Thank you

Comment: @Jeeped From my search it seems that countif is used to count how many cells contains specific text. What I need is to highlight cells that are duplicated more than specific number.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by mixing the `countif()` formula with conditional formatting.

Step 1: Select the entire column in question starting with the top most row (i.e. A1 to A25)

Step 2: Add a conditional format to these cells (Excel 2016 > Home > Styles > Conditional Formatting > New Rule)

Step 3: Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format

Step 4: Input this formula; Note you may have to modify this formula slightly

`=COUNTIF(A1:A25,$A1)>=9`

- Formula Breakdown:

  - `A1:A25` the entire range in question
  - `$A1` the top most row location (Note: This value must match your    first selected cell in your array)
  - `>=9` is the statement to compare the results too. The 9 indicates    that you want to see more than 9 duplicates of THAT cell
    value.

Step 5: Add a color format to the cell (this way it is easy to spot the duplicates). (Click the "Format" button, then add the proper formatting you wish to see)

Click "OK" then click "Apply"

At this point you should see all of the duplicates that have more than 9 entries.